# Unable to locate package timeshift, deleted /var folder

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I accidentally deleted my /var folder in ubuntu and now I am trying to back up and reinstall ubuntu, following this website's step-by-step: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-system-backup-and-restore. However, when I try to install timeshift (`sudo apt install timeshift`) I get `E: Unable to locate package timeshift`.
When I run `sudo apt update` I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2fVq.png):

```
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease [12.9 kB]
Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.7WSRQF for passing config to apt-key
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu focal InRelease [17.5 kB]
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.oYNeaO for passing config to apt-key
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease [23.8 kB]
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.uvGnpS for passing config to apt-key
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.de91MW for passing config to apt-key
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.f6AojY for passing config to apt-key
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.NR1QN2 for passing config to apt-key
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.XvVS49 for passing config to apt-key
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.7WSRQF for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu focal InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.oYNeaO for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.uvGnpS for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.de91MW for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.f6AojY for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.NR1QN2 for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.XvVS49 for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I checked if the package was available for my version of ubuntu [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/), and yes, it was. The universe repository is enabled, too.
I tried to install shutter and nmap and I got the same error.
I would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your steps and error codes as text, not images.

Comment: Was Timeshift installed and configured before you've deleted `/var`? Because if not, it's not going to help you now.

Comment: No, it was not... So it's not possible to install it now?

Comment: Is there any other way to back up my files so I can uninstall and install ubuntu without losing them?

Comment: Yes - just copy them to a safe place (actually you should have backups set up ahead of time and ready to restore). The idea behind Timeshift is that it makes snapshots of your system files (_not personal files_) regularly to make recovery in situations like this relatively painless.

Comment: @gronostaj Ok, thank you! I was thinking of copying them to a bucket on google cloud and restoring them afterwards. Would you advise me to do so? I don't know much about google cloud so I don't know if it even works or not...

Comment: Personally I'd prefer a USB drive. It will be faster than uploading unless the Internet connection is very fast and I wouldn't be uploading my personal files to someone else's computer. At the end of the day anything will work as long as it's reliable enough, fast enough and satisfies your privacy requirements.